# flag provided but not defined: --wsaddr

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to set up my eth node with this command line, but i keep getting an error that its undefined:

```
geth --syncmode "light" -cache=2048 --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins '*' --wsport 8546 --wsapi 'web3,eth,net'
```

did i mistype something?

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Those switches were deprecated for several releases. It was replaced by `--ws.addr`.

Check the [geth documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options).